# Create Billing Plan is erroring with Malformed_Request

Tags: c#, rest, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I am trying to create a billing plan with the request below. (It's valid JSON) and I've checked the request and seems to be correct based on the example requests given on PayPal's (Irrespective of this, I've tried using the stock example and It wont work.

```
POST https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/billing-plans HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer A015Ocv2vKmHg2NY2PNSbGEIN5jWHsZFKr.63kJzvtNaeII
Host: api.sandbox.paypal.com
Content-Length: 775
Expect: 100-continue

{
"name": "Membership Fee",
"description": "Monthly Fee with Trial Month",
"type": "INFINITE",
"payment_definitions": [
    {
        "name": "Plan",
        "type": "REGULAR",
        "frequency": "MONTH",
        "frequency_interval": "1",
        "amount": {
            "value": "15",
            "currency": "GBP"
        },
        "cycles": "12"
    },
    {
        "name": "First Month Free Trial",
        "type": "TRIAL",
        "frequency": "MONTH",
        "frequency_interval": "1",
        "amount": {
            "value": "0.01",
            "currency": "GBP"
        },
        "cycles": "1"
    }
],
"merchant_preferences": {
    "setup_fee": {
        "value": "0",
        "currency": "GBP"
    },
    "return_url": "http://app.URLREMOVED.co.uk/complete",
    "cancel_url": "http://app.URLREMOVED.co.uk/cancel",
    "auto_bill_amount": "YES",
    "initial_fail_amount_action": "CONTINUE",
    "max_fail_attempts": "12"
}
}
```

Response I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
PROXY_SERVER_INFO: host=slcsbjava4.slc.paypal.com;threadId=35463
Paypal-Debug-Id: 8437249fdc6d1
SERVER_INFO: paymentsplatformserv:v1.payments.billing-    plans&CalThreadId=127&TopLevelTxnStartTime=147d9bc0282&Host=slcsbjm3.slc.paypal.com&pid=25126
Content-Language: *
Date: Fri, 15 Aug 2014 12:54:42 GMT
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 213
Connection: close

{"name":"MALFORMED_REQUEST","message":"Incoming JSON request does not map to API     request","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#MALFORMED_REQUEST","debug_id":"8437249fdc6d1"}
```

As far as I can see the request is correct, I'm authenticating, I've got the correct URL, anyone spot what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

You have `autobill_amount` and it should be `auto_bill_amount`.  You also have `initial_amount_fail_action` and it should be `initial_fail_amount_action`.

Comment: Fixed that, and also initial_amount_fail_action was wrong, so corrected that aswell, however, it's still failing

Answer (score 0):

Right, It was my error not setting the cycles to 0, as this is a continuing payment until someone cancels it, it should be 0 not 12.

So, Corrected request (Which works)

```
{
"name": "Membership Fee",
"description": "Monthly Fee with Trial Month",
"type": "infinite",
"payment_definitions": [
    {
        "name": "Free Trial",
        "type": "REGULAR",
        "frequency": "MONTH",
        "frequency_interval": "1",
        "amount": {
            "value": "15",
            "currency": "GBP"
        },
        "cycles": "0"
    },
    {
        "name": "First Month Free Trial",
        "type": "TRIAL",
        "frequency": "MONTH",
        "frequency_interval": "1",
        "amount": {
            "value": "0.01",
            "currency": "GBP"
        },
        "cycles": "1"
    }
],
"merchant_preferences": {
    "setup_fee": {
        "value": "1",
        "currency": "GBP"
    },
    "return_url": "http://app.URLREMOVED.co.uk/complete",
    "cancel_url": "http://app.URLREMOVED.co.uk/cancel",
    "auto_bill_amount": "YES",
    "initial_fail_amount_action": "CONTINUE",
    "max_fail_attempts": "0"
}
}
```